# Storage arrays with nested mappings do not support .push(<arg>)

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I have a struct with a nested mapping which I am instantiating and trying to push to an array, but I'm receiving the following error on the line i try to push:

`Storage arrays with nested mappings do not support .push(<arg>).`

Its obvious what the compiler is complaining about, my struct has a mapping and im trying to perform a push. Is this fundamentally not allowed or is there something I can change in my implementation to make this work? I'm using solidity 0.8.0.

Code:

```
struct Dividend {
    mapping(address => bool) claimed;
    uint256 pool;
}
Dividend[] public dividends;

function createDividends() public {
    Dividend storage d;
    d.pool = dividendPool;
    dividends.push(d);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mappings cannot be copied around through assignment either in `storage` or `memory` and can only be referenced. A work around is the following snippet.

```
struct Dividend {
    mapping(address => bool) claimed;
    uint256 pool;
}
Dividend[] public dividends;

function createDividends() public {
    uint256 idx = dividends.length;
    dividends.push();
    Dividend storage d = dividends[idx];
    d.pool = 10;
    d.claimed[msg.sender] = true;
}
```